Method for comitting the previous message rather than the most recently read one with Apache Kafka?
Is there a way to commit the previously read message rather than the current (most recently read message) when consuming data from a Kafka Consumer?
A brief explanation as to why I want to do this:
I am writing a data archiving tool, which will split events read from Kafka into different files depending on the event date. Each event contains a timestamp from which the date value can be obtained.
When reading events, we cannot know that we have all the events for the current date until we fetch an event where the timestamp has rolled over to the next date.
When such an event is found where the date rolls, we know we have a stable commit point. The file can be written to disk and flushed, and a commit operation can be made to Kafka. However, the most recently fetched event should not be comitted, because it is for a new date, and therefore should be saved to a different file.
Therefore, if the process fails, we need to be able to read this event again.
There is no peek like operation with Kafka.
Note that partitioning can be ignored because all events have the same fixed key, and so all events are assigned to the same partition.
Basically, you don't know the current file has all the data until you find an event which comes from Kafka with a different date. The problem is, you have now read that event from Kafka, so there is no way to "unread" it before committing. You have to commit, but if the process crashes, this event will not be read again, because it has been committed. This would cause data loss.
Here is some example code.
use core::str;

use rdkafka::consumer::Consumer;
use rdkafka::Message;
use chrono;
use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
struct Event {
    event_timestamp: chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {

    let config =
        rdkafka::config::ClientConfig::new()
        .set("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.x:9092")
        .set("client.id", "client.id")
        .set("group.id", "group.id")
        .set("enable.auto.commit", "false")
        .set("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
        .set("isolation.level", "read_committed")
        .to_owned();

    let consumer: rdkafka::consumer::BaseConsumer =
        config
        .create()
        .expect("invalid client configuration");

    let topic_example = "example_topic";
    let topics = [topic_example];
    let result = consumer.subscribe(&topics).expect("failed to subscribe");

    let mut optional_last_event: Option<Event> = None;

    loop {

        let poll_timeout = std::time::Duration::from_secs(10);
        let optional_message = consumer.poll(poll_timeout);

        match optional_message {
            Some(maybe_message) => {

                let message = maybe_message.expect("some message failure");

                let optional_payload = message.payload().expect("payload is None");
                
                let message_str = str::from_utf8(payload).expect("invalid UTF-8");
                let event = serde_json::from_str::<Event>(message_str).unwrap();

                let event_timestamp = event.event_timestamp;
                let event_date = event_timestamp.date_naive();

                match &optional_last_event {
                    Some(last_event) => {
                        let last_event_date = last_event.event_timestamp.date_naive();
                        if last_event_date != event_date {

                            //process_message(event);

                            // commit the last message, not the current one
                            //consumer. commit ( ... ) ?
                        }
                        else {
                            optional_last_event = Some(event);
                        }
                    }

                    None => {
                        optional_last_event = Some(event);
                    }
                }
            }

            None => {
                println!("waiting for messages");
            }
        }
    }
}


I'm not aware about commit previous kafka option. As a suggestion from Java, have you checked KafkaCosnumer seek method. It will allow you to consume again committed event if you store in a DB it's offset and partition.

The issue is, you cannot in general seek to an arbitrary offset. The reason is you do not know which offset values exist, or if they do exist, if they are regular events or metadata. You can only seek to the beginning or the end. Certainly, you should not rely on this behaviour because you may be asking for an offset which you do not know exists. In general, an application should be agnostic to the specific values of offsets used by Kafka, as this is an internal implementation detail.

Still, I like your idea and you should leave this answer available for other people to learn from. Not many people know about this. It is a subtle detail and I don't think it is well explained by any currently available resources.

In Java, poll() returns a ConsumerRecord instance, which in addition ta key value pair, has offset value, which can be used afterwards, I assume that in case if offset is missing the earliest will be picked.

There is also an interesting example here. search for :Consuming Records with Specific Offsets title

Again, I like the idea, but as this example shows, it requires a known offset to start from. There is actually a more relevant example in that link under the section Commit Specified Offset. This shows on method of doing it, assuming you are using a Java API. The small change would be to commit record.offset() rather than record.offset()+1, to ensure the current event will be re-consumed in the event of a failure.

Unfortunatly Rust does not provide exactly the same API as Java does. I think the Java client, Python client (official one), rdkafka (C++) and the Rust wrapper around rdkaka all present different APIs. Which is incredibly painful.

How I solved this problem.
First note that some careful thought is required when determing which message or offset should be committed.
Let me explain the two cases:

If you choose to commit a message the Kafka semantics are generally such that the message offset + 1 is committed
The reason is that the committed offset determines which message will be fetched next by Kafka
Example: You fetch message with offset 1000. You call commit with this message as an argument. Kafka commits the offset 1000 + 1 = 1001. If the process then dies or otherwise restarts, the next time you fetch, Kafka returns the message with offset 1001.
On the other hand, if you choose to commit an offset (usually in the form of a topic, partition and offset tuple) then Kafka does not perform any additional math to add 1 to the offset. This means that you will get back the same message again after a restart.

Hopefully the difference between the two cases is clear, as this is important.
Therefore, if you want the same behaviour as I was looking for you have two options.

Commit the current message offset using the commit function which takes a topic, partition and offset tuple.
Keep a copy of the previous message (most likely as an Option<OwnedMessage> and commit this message after the current message has been processed.

Option 1 is by far the most simple to implement. Option 2 may not even be possible. It depends on whether you can realistically call detach on a BorrowedMessage to convert it to an OwnedMessage.
